# Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory'

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

We are using RedisTemplate to make redis calls.

```
 @Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
    // Replace the default serialization with Jackson2JsonRedisSerialize
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);

    jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    // Set the value of the serialization rules and key serialization rules
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);

    redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setEnableDefaultSerializer(true);
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

We make around ***1K calls*** per minutes e.g. **redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(HASH_KEY, key);**

we are getting below error:

```
stack_trace: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:212)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:611)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:340)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:168)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
```

We are using SpringBoot + Redis 2.8.24 + JDK11.

Any Inputs?

Comment: The error seems unrelated to your "1k calls per minute" - can you elaboarte a bit?
As a nit: you are not supposed to call `afterPropertiesSet()` manually, Spring will do it automatically for all @Component / @Bean objects.

The error seems to indicate that the application is not starting at all, not after a certain amoutn of calls.

Comment: The reason I mentioned about 1K is to give idea about traffic. Not all calls are failing intermittently we are getting this error. One doubt was if there is any limit around connection pooling which might be causing this error.

Answer (score 4):

The following way may work for you.

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private Integer port;
    @Value("${spring.redis.database}")
    private Integer database;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port);
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(database);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(String.class));
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(String.class));
        return template;
    }
}
```

You can set the serialization as required and can access data based on that.

```java
public class RedisHashRepository {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisHashRepository.class);

    private HashOperations hashOperations;

    @Autowired
    public RedisHashRepository(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        this.hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
    }

    public String get(String mainKey,String key) {
        return (String) hashOperations.get(mainKey, key);
    }
}
```